# Ninject Context Binding in Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

MVC 3, Ninject 2.2.

I have a scenario where I need to temporarily override a binding. The override is just for the duration of an Action in a Controller.

What I need is something like this:

```
[HttpGet, Authorize(Users="MySpecialAccount")]
public ActionResult Report(string userName) {
  var reportViewModel = new ReportViewModel();

  using(var block = Kernel.BeginBlock() {
    var principal = //load principal info based on userName;
    block.Rebind<IMyPrincipal>().ToConstant(principal);
    reportViewModel = GetViewModel(); //calls bunch of repos to hydrate view model that reference IMyPrincipal
  }

  return View(reportViewModel);
}
```

### Background:

The application uses windows authentication. I have a a custom provider that loads a custom principal. We inject this custom principal into our repos/services/etc and help us load the appropriate data based on the authenticated user. That has all worked great for a long time. Now I have a scenario where I am using impersonation in one action. The reason is probably beyond scope, but basically I am using an HTMLToPDF writer that launches a separate process to load the HTML/Action under a different account. Anyways, because I am impersonating in this one action, all of my repos can't load the correct info since it is not the user that made the request, makes sense. So I send in a parameter of "who" we need to run the report for, and I need to Rebind the custom principal temporarily.

Hope this makes sense. Here are snippets of the current code that loads the custom principal.

```
In Global.asax:
protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object source, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //goes to db and loads additional info about logged on user. We use this info in repos/services to load correct data for logged on user.
            var principal = new PrincipalFactory().GetPrincipal(e.Identity); 

            e.User = principal;
        }
    }


//Ninject Binding    
Bind<IMyPrincipal>().ToProvider(new MyPrincipalProvider());

//Provider
public class MyPrincipalProvider : Provider<IMyPrincipal>
{
    protected override IMyPrincipal CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var principal = HttpContext.Current.User as IMyPrincipal;

        return principal ?? new UnauthenticatedPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("Not Authenticated"));
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility that comes to mind is to use a custom authorize attribute:

```
public class ImpersonateAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // or if you wanted to load the username from the request:
        // string username = httpContext.Request["username"];

        IPrincipal principal = // load principal info based on username;

        // Swap the principal for this action
        httpContext.User = principal;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpGet]
[ImpersonateAuthorize(Users="MySpecialAccount")]
public ActionResult Report(string userName) 
{
    // Here this.User will be the custom principal you loaded in 
    // the authorize attribute

    var reportViewModel = new ReportViewModel();

    return View(reportViewModel);
}
```

Another approach is to do this at your DI framework configuration level:

```
public class MyPrincipalProvider : Provider<IPrincipal>
{
    protected override IPrincipal CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals("report", currentAction, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals("users", currentController, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            IPrincipal principal = // load principal info based on username;
            return principal;
        }

        var principal = httpContext.User as IPrincipal;
        return principal ?? new UnauthenticatedPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("Not Authenticated"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin, I tried the first option and I think it may be too late in the cycle for Ninject to pick up a different httpContext.User. Since the repos are injected in the controller, they have already been instantiated w/ the other principal, so it doesn't look at HttpContext.User after I swap it. I am testing the second approach. Thanks for your suggestions, very appreciated!

Comment: After little more thinking the first approach should work if I don't inject the dependencies via the constructor, I can change those to use service locator after I swap the principal...